# How do I make Title property mandatory on a custom content type?

Tags: content-type, field-definition

As title says, I want to use the standard SharePoint Title property, but I need to make it mandatory. It's not an option to do this through the 'Documents' settings of the UI, I need to define it as Required="TRUE" in XML. I have found out the GUID of the Title field and added it to the FieldRefs and added Required="TRUE" to it but it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered on this forum previously.

Check out this link: 
[How to adjust the title column in custom content type in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/how-to-adjust-the-title-column-in-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010)

It was the top result on Google when I was trying to find you some relevant reference material.

Also check out this link: http://www.pranavsharma.com/blog/2010/07/12/cannot-modify-title-field-in-content-type-declaration/

Little different approach, but it's still relevant.