# SharePoint 2007, Columns, force required

Tags: 2007

So i already have "auto generated" columns on one of my site, but lately people have been using it wrongfully (if that's a correct word). I wanted to make couple columns required but came to find out that there is no option for me to make it required. I do not want to create new column since all the information already there i wont be able to transfer them to the new filed. so is there a way to make them required? I am guessing these fields are called "sealed"? Not sure, i am new to sharepoint.

Some screenshots:

Columns:

[image]

Date: (would like to make it required)
[image]

As you may see no option to enable required nor delete. Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some of the OOTB columns you won't find the option to make it Required from UI. We need to have some workaround for it.

Ex...Title, Created By(Author),Modified By(Editor).

For this please have a look at at the answers from other post.

[How to adjust the title column in custom content type in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/how-to-adjust-the-title-column-in-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010)
http://www.pranavsharma.com/blog/2010/07/12/cannot-modify-title-field-in-content-type-declaration/
http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/required-feature-metadata-column.aspx

But for the customs fields you will the option to make it Required from UI.

Comment: Yes, but i didn't wanted to go the custom fields route. since i wont be able to transfer data from ootb columns. Thanks for the help, ill go read up on those link.

Comment: Pls mark the answer as correct if its helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Will do if there is no other way(s) of dealing with OOTB columns